# PostgreSQL: Calculate percentage of rows with a column above a certain value

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, percentage, threshold

Suppose I have table of values:

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Value |
+----+-------+
| 1  |  2    |
| 2  |  9    |
| 3  |  5    |
| 4  |  5    |
| 5  |  8    |
| 6  |  1    |
+----+-------+
```

How can I calculate the percentage of rows who's value is higher than a given threshold:

Eg, with a threshold of *'higher than 5'*, how could I query to get the following:

```
+-------+------------------+
| Total | Percent above 5  |
+-------+------------------+
|   6   |     33.33        |
+-------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*),
       avg( (value > 5)::int ) * 100 as percentage_above_5
from t;
```

Comment: Is the percentage correct? Maybe a `ratio_to_report` instead of `sum`?

Comment: Hello @GordonLinoff, just a question, why do you cast to int the expression `(value > 5)`?

Comment: @Alexis . . . I don't think that `avg()` works on booleans.  You could also use `avg(case when value > 5 then 1 else 0 end)`.

Comment: Many thanks @GordonLinoff, I understand now, it's a boolean!, I guess if you cast it they convert to 1 if true and that adds up to the average to be multiplied finally.